# Is it possible to get code coverage of ctypes shared library imported in Python?

Tags: python, c, code-coverage, ctypes

I am using ctypes to wrap some C code so that I can write tests with python.
I would like to know if it is possible to obtain code coverage information when the library is imported like this:

```
import ctypes
_lib = ctypes.CDLL('/path/to/mylib.so')
```

I know that it is possible to do this when compiling with the `--coverage` option but the code coverage information will be available after running the executable.

Comment: First, you need to instrument the C code, fortunately GCC does this for you with one option or the other, as you seem to know already. Second, you need to run the code, and it will accumulate the required data. Only after finishing, you can use GCOV to obtain the coverage data. -- So, what is your issue? Do you want to evaluate the coverage _while the tested code is still running_?

Answer (score 0):

As thebusybee pointed out it in the comments, I need to instrument the code adding the compiler option and then run the python code to obtain code coverage details:

> First, you need to instrument the C code, fortunately GCC does this for you with one option or the other, as you seem to know already. Second, you need to run the code, and it will accumulate the required data. Only after finishing, you can use GCOV to obtain the coverage data.

Comment: Note that this is a self-answer from the OP, not a "thank you" post. I've made some edits for the OP, which will hopefully make that clearer.